# jquery .remove() shifting indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I've got a mtuli-select box called AgentIDList2.  When I select a bunch of the options and hit a delete button I wish those options to be totally removed from AgentIDList2.  Instead what's happening, is the index is shifting everytime I delete an element so my code doesn't work.  Any ideas on how to get around this:

```
function remove_agents() {
var List = $('#AgentIDList2');
List = List[0]; 
selected = new Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < List.options.length; i++) {
    if (List.options[i].selected) {
        selected.push(i);
    }
}

// Break it out like this so we don't screw up the indices and pick the wrong item
for (i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
    List.options.remove(selected[i]);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$('#AgentIDList2 option:selected').remove();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/9N62Y/).

Comment: That's magical.  So much more elegant too. AND a wicked awesome example too.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries JohnZ, spending a little time learning the jQuery API will help you tremendously and save you a lot of time in future development. I would give it a glance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_agents() {
var List = $('#AgentIDList2')[0];
selected = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < List.options.length; i++) {
    if (List.options[i].selected) {
        selected.push(i);
    }
}

// Break it out like this so we don't screw up the indices and pick the wrong item
for (i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
    List.options.remove(selected[i--]);
    }
}
```

Cleaned it up a bit, but the thing that fixes it is manually adjusting your index in the for loop (`i--`)